# Converting void* to std::vector<std::uint8_t>

Tags: c++, type-conversion, stdvector, void-pointers

I have the API with the prototype:

```
mani(void* data, std::size_t s, std::size_t& ds);
```

This function reads the server response into `data`, `s` is the size of the buffer fixed to 100, and `ds` is the number of bytes received.

I'm trying to save the data straight into a vector of `std::vector<std::uint8_t>` by doing this:

```
std::vector<std::uint8_t> recv_data = {};
mani(&recv_data[0] , 100, ds);
```

But it is not working. Could you please provide any suggestions you might have?

Comment: Ask yourself: How many elements are in vector after doing `std::vector<std::uint8_t> recv_data = {};`?

Comment: That would be 0, but I don't understand why!

Comment: You need to tell it how many elements you want if you want it to have a certain number of elements. like `std::vector<std::uint8_t> recv_data(elements_wanted)`

Comment: Got it! Thank you. My expectations were that since std::vector is a dynamic structure, I didn't need to specify the size beforehand.

Comment: It is, but in order to get that behavior you have to use it's member functions like `push_back`.  That will grow the vector when you exceed its capacity.  When you just pass `&recv_data[0]`, vector has no idea you are writing into the memory the vector holds, so it can't grow to accommodate you.